# Can't terminate PHP daemon process

Tags: ssh, terminal, process, php, daemon

I've started a PHP daemon process via SSH with

```
php ./my-script.php --daemon
```

Now I want to quit this process, but I can't.

It's still active in the foreground of my shell and I've hit `CTRL + C` multiple times, but to no avail.

Comment: What does your script do with the --daemon option ?

Comment: You probably want to issue a SIGKILL (Ctrl-\\) rather than a SIGTERM (Ctrl-C). Another alternative is to issue (Ctrl-Z) and then `kill %1`.

Comment: @XTian I'm using [Tiny Tiny RSS](http://tt-rss.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attempt to create a 2nd session on that server and find your original process running the php script `ps ax | grep scriptname` note the pid, and then kill it with `kill -9 pid`

edit 1

Does suspend work <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to create a second session. :(

Comment: `CTRL + Z` did it.